# A Needle in the Haystack "a coding question ask in gfg"

Tags: python

**qsn body:-**

Given 2 strings Needle and Haystack. The given Needle is distorted in nature and can be shuffled and rearranged in any order. You have to check whether the Needle is part of the Haystack or not. ie- the given string needle is a shuffled substring of string haystack or not.

Input:
First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each test case, first line consists of the needle and second line consists of the haystack.

Output:
Print Yes if the given string needle is a shuffled substring of haystack. Otherwise print No.

Your Task:
Complete the function isShuffledSubstring() that takes the given needle and haystack as input and returns a boolean value.

Constraints:
1 <= haystack.length() <= 1000
1 <= needle.length() <= 1000

Example:

Sample Input:

`onetwofour hellofourtwooneworld`

`roseyellow yellow`

`geekforgeeks ekegorfkeegsgeek`

Sample Output:

`Yes`

`No`

`Yes`

Explanation:

Testcase 1 :

needle `onetwofour` can be rearranged as `fourtwoone` which is a substring of haystack `hellofourtwooneworld`.

Testcase 2 :

Length of needle is greater than haystack. Hence needle is not a substring of haystack.

Testcase 3 :

needle `geekforgeeks` can be rearranged as `orfkeegsgeek` which is a substring of haystack `ekegorfkeegsgeek`.

**required function  ==:- **

```py
def isShuffledSubstring(needle, haystack): 
    # Your code goes here
    if len(needle)>len(haystack):
        return False
    Map1={}
    Map2={}
    for i in needle:
        if i in Map1:
            Map1[i]+=1
        else:
            Map1[i]=1
    for i in haystack:
        if i in Map2:
            Map2[i]+=1
        else:
            Map2[i]=1
    for i in Map1:
        if i in Map2:
            if Map2[i]<Map1[i]:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

it passed test cases but not full test cases.
Sorry,All the test cases are not with me as it is part of coding competition.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check(unordered_map<char,int> &_map)
{
    bool flag = true;
    for(auto i = _map.begin(); i!= _map.end(); i++)
    {
        if(i->second !=0)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

bool isShuffledSubstring(string needle, string haystack) 
{
    int len1 = needle.length();
    int len2 = haystack.length();

    if(len1>len2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    unordered_map<char,int> _map;

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
    {
        if(_map.find(needle[i]) == _map.end())
        {
            _map.insert(make_pair(needle[i],1));
        }
        else
        {
            _map[needle[i]] +=1;
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
    {
        if(_map.find(haystack[i]) != _map.end())
        {
            _map[haystack[i]] -=1;
        }

    }
    if(check(_map))
    {
         return true;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j= len1;

    while(j<len2)
    {
        if(_map.find(haystack[i]) != _map.end())
        {
                _map[haystack[i]] +=1;
        }
        if(_map.find(haystack[j]) != _map.end())
        {
            _map[haystack[j]] -= 1;
           if(check(_map))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
       i++;
       j++;
    }
   return false;
}
```